# Force the standby mode for a monitor

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, lcd

When a monitor is in standby-mode (in current Windows OS), it will end its standby mode on **keystroke** or **mousemovement**.
This is the behaviour that I want to change. Is there an application, setting or command (for cmd) that I could use to force the monitor stay in standby mode (and thus ignoring the mouse/keyboard)?

I guess a solution would be to toggle (enable/disable) graphic-card output on keystroke, but I don't know if such tool/feature/command exists.

Attention! This question is not "How to put a monitor into standby"

Comment: This question is not "How to put a monitor into standby". So what exactly is your question? It is very unclear. Do you want to stop it waking up from standby? Only wake up with a particular keystroke?

Comment: It should not be activated on mouse/keystroke. I want to enable/disable that with a setting.

Comment: So how to you intend to wake up the monitor?

Comment: I guess that depends on the method that I use for forced-standby. So if (for example) I would use a keystroke to force the standby it could use the same keystroke to wake the monitor up again.

Comment: This might be relevant [How do I wake up my Windows monitors once turned off by power settings?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/332649)

Comment: Have you done any research or experimenting as yet?

Comment: @CharlieRB I've taken a look into system management, checked hardware-settings, looked for posts in stackexchange, asked my colleagues (IT guys), used google.  

And your link might help, but the effort to start programming for a setting is really high. There might be an easier way. For example toggle peripheral input via keyboard-shortcut - but even that - I couldn't find.